# how to read system properties programmatically using android ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to get the value of `wlan.interface` in ndk codes, but I can't find some documents or information about how to do it.

btw: I tried with `__system_property_get` and failed.

Comment: `adb shell getprop` is useful to get a list of all properties. You may want to use it to identify the right key to use with `__system_property_get`.

Comment: I used the right key "wifi.interface" and still got nothing